# how can i redirect page in php with echo or header?(in if condition)

Tags: php

Ok, I tried echo and header to redirect my page when the password is correct but the page isn't redirecting. I tried several time but nothing is happening

i am using xammp and php7 for this site.

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    // get retrieved row
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // create array
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "Successfully Login!",
header( 'Location: ./index.html' ),
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "username" => $row['username']

    );
```

in phpstorm when i am using header( 'Location: ./index.html' ), it telling me that i am using void.

Comment: You wrote the header() function insight your array. Please write it after the last semicolon. But everything you have in your array will be lost. What Is your intention of this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a broken array.

```php
<?php
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        // get retrieved row
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // create array
        $user_arr=array(
            "status" => true,
            "message" => "Successfully Login!",
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "username" => $row['username']
        );
        // Moved out of $user_arr
        header( 'Location: ./index.html' );
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Always used exit(); after header('Location: ...');